# How do you get a list of DRM plug-ins (agents) installed on a device?

Tags: android, drm

The [documentation for the android DRM package](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/drm/package-summary.html) says "Common uses of the DRM API include ... Determining which DRM plug-ins (agents) are installed on a device".

The only method I can find in the DRM package for doing that is [DrmManagerClient.getAvailableDrmEngines()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/drm/DrmManagerClient.html#getAvailableDrmEngines()). This method does work, in the sense that it returns a string array containing names of DRM agents. Is that what the above statement about determining which plug-ins are installed is referring to?

However, that list, at least in some cases, completely contradicts the results of the newer method [MediaDrm.isCryptoSchemeSupported()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaDrm.html#isCryptoSchemeSupported(java.util.UUID)), which is in the `android.Media` package.

Examples:

### HTC Desire 550 running Android 7:

- `getAvailableDrmEngines()`:

  - Playready DRM plug-in
  - DriveActivator plug-in
  - MirrorLink plug-in
  - OMA HTC
- `isCryptoSchemeSupported()`:

  - Common PSSH / CENC
  - WideVine

### Samsung SM-G870A running Android 5.1.1:

- `getAvailableDrmEngines()`:

  - Widevine DRM plug-in
  - OMA V1 Forward Lock
  - (blank plug-in name)
  - Playready plug-in
  - TZ Playready plug-in
- `isCryptoSchemeSupported()`:

  - Common PSSH / CENC
  - WideVine

One developer, who has a very popular DRM-related tool in the Google Play store, kindly told me that he would consider the `DrmManagerClient` approach outdated / not commonly used anymore.

That being the case, it makes sense to use `MediaDrm.isCryptoSchemeSupported()` where possible, i.e. API level 18 or later. But MediaDrm doesn't offer a way to get a list of supported crypto schemes / agents / plug-ins; you just have to try the ones you're interested in. You could try putting known crypto scheme UUIDs from [the DASHIF list](http://dashif.org/identifiers/protection/) into your code, and try them all. But that list will likely change over the years.

Which brings us back to the original question:

**How do you get an (accurate) list of DRM plug-ins installed on a device?**

Related questions feeding into that, for the purpose of clarifying the main question:

- Is the [original claim in the documentation about this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/drm/package-summary.html) referring to `DrmManagerClient.getAvailableDrmEngines()`, or something else?
- If it's referring to `DrmManagerClient.getAvailableDrmEngines()`, but the latter gives wrong results on newer devices, why isn't it deprecated? Is it a widespread bug in manufacturers' implementations of Android?

  - Or is it possible that by "supported crypto schemes" they really do mean something different from (and independent of) installed DRM engines / agents? Sure, the concepts of DRM plug-in and encryption scheme are technically distinct, yet the answers seem to cover the same territory. (And the [MediaDrm docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaDrm.html) suggest that "DRM scheme" and "crypto scheme" are being used interchangeably: "It accesses the *DRM-scheme-identifying* UUID, typically from metadata in the content, and uses this UUID to construct an instance of a MediaDrm object that is able to support the *DRM scheme* required by the content. *Crypto schemes* are assigned 16 byte UUIDs. The method isCryptoSchemeSupported(UUID) can be used to query if a given *scheme* is supported on the device.")  If these two methods really give independent information that are both correct, then how can the HTC support WideVine crypto scheme without a WideVine DRM plug-in available?
- If `DrmManagerClient.getAvailableDrmEngines()` isn't reliable, is there another way to get a list, other than trying all the UUIDs you can find?

Comment: It would be great to see a definitive answer to this question, but I suspect that your note "Sure, the concepts of DRM plug-in and encryption scheme are technically distinct, yet the answers seem to cover the same territory" is probably a good summary - the mechanisms overlap but are independent so the combined view may not have been rationalised. Another twist is that most DRM's have different levels, and there may be a distinction between the different levels, e.g. whether they are tied to a HW key, which affects the answers.